# Стоит ли возвращать массив вместо объекта?

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, шаблоны-проектирования, конструктор

```js
class cardPool {
  _pool = [];
  _suits = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
  
  constructor() {
    this._shuffle();

    return this._pool;
  }

    _shuffle() {
        ...
    }
}
```

`this._pool` возвращает просто массив из 52 перемешанных карт, и я хочу получить его в другом классе.

Стоит ли делать так или это плохой подход?

Comment: массив - это объект, в js вам вообще не дают работать с не объектами

Comment: А как собираетесь добраться до методов класса, имея только массив? А если методы не нужны, и shuffle используется только один раз, возвращает массив, который больше не будет иметь отношение к классу, есть смысл вместо класса использовать обычную функцию) Которая будет сама по себе, или, например, будет являться методом другого класса.

Comment: спасибо, я думал об этом но пришел к идее что не могу понять стоит ли смешивать процедурный код и ооп подход. т.ё. если я выбираю использовать
ооп то я все процессы в программе делаю на классах и обьектах, без примесей обычных функций и процедурного подхода. видимо правильно всё это совмещать в программе
по мере необходимости?

Comment: пихать везде объекты - это не ооп подход :)